# Better code for accessing fields in a matlab structure array?

Tags: matlab, reflection, structure

I have a matlab structure array `Modles1` of size (1x180) that has fields `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `z`.

I want to understand how many distinct values there are in each of the fields.  i.e.

```
max(grp2idx([foo(:).a]))
```

The above works if the field `a` is a double.  `{foo(:).a}` needs to be used in the case where the field a is a string/char.

Here's my current code for doing this.  I hate having to use the eval, and what is essentially a switch statement.  Is there a better way?

```
names = fieldnames(Models1);
for ix = 1 : numel(names)
    className = eval(['class(Models1(1).',names{ix},')']);
    if strcmp('double', className) || strcmp('logical',className)
        eval([' values = [Models1(:).',names{ix},'];']);
    elseif strcmp('char', className)
        eval([' values = {Models1(:).',names{ix},'};']);
    else
        disp(['Unrecognized class: ', className]);
    end
    % this line requires the statistics toolbox.
    [g, gn, gl] = grp2idx(values);
    fprintf('%30s : %4d\n',names{ix},max(g));
end
```

Comment: The use of eval is indeed best minimized, but a switch is not bad practice. If you want it to look nicer you can use the actual switch case syntax.

Comment: @Dennis It isn't a switch as such that I was not liking, it was that I had to switch to handle different class types.  That strikes me as just ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, there is a better way. Surprisingly, MATLAB allows you to access the struct fields using a key string without `eval`, for instance:

```
Models1(1).(names{ix})
```

so instead, you can write this:

```
className = class(Models1(1).(names{ix});
...
values = [Models1(:).(names{ix})];
...
values = {Models1(:).(names{ix})};
```

Also, instead of using `class` and `strcmp`, you can just test the same conditions with [`isa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html):

```
v1 = Models1(1).(names{ix});
if (isa(v1, 'double') || isa(v1, 'logical'))
    values = [Models1(:).(names{ix})];
    % # ...
elseif (isa(v1, 'char'))
    values = {Models1(:).(names{ix})};
    % # ...
else
    disp(['Unrecognized class: ', class(v1)]);
end
```

It should be much faster.

Comment: I am very surprised I didn't see that in the documentation.  Sweet!